# displaying hidden rows after I read an xlsx file using python and display it in linux terminal

Tags: python, linux, dataframe, xlsx

the following was my python code to display a section of a xlsx file in the linux terminal:

```
 import pandas as pd
  2 require_cols=[1,3,6,7,8,9]
  3 df=pd.read_excel('NGXP_6_2_2_dimensions.xlsx',sheet_name='3.1.1 AT&T NBE',usecols=require_cols,skiprows=63,skipfooter=94)
  4 df.dropna(inplace=True)
  5 #df=df.query("Type=='EXF-CTRL'")
  6 #df1=df.head(-96)
  7 print(df)
```

but the out appears with some of the portions hidden:

```
   Application Helm  ... Unnamed: 9
0           Type     ...      RAM L
2          EXF-CTRL  ...        4.4
6          EXF-CTRL  ...        0.6
8          EXF-CTRL  ...        2.2
10         EXF-CTRL  ...        0.4
11         EXF-CTRL  ...        8.8
12         EXF-CTRL  ...        2.2
13         EXF-CTRL  ...        4.4
14         EXF-CTRL  ...        4.4
15         EXF-CTRL  ...        8.8
16         EXF-CTRL  ...        1.1
17         EXF-CTRL  ...        8.8
20         EXF-CTRL  ...        0.1
24         EXF-CTRL  ...        2.2
26         EXF-CTRL  ...        2.2
27         EXF-CTRL  ...        8.8
28         EXF-CTRL  ...        2.2
29         EXF-CTRL  ...        4.4
30         EXF-CTRL  ...        4.4
31         EXF-CTRL  ...        2.2
32         EXF-CTRL  ...        0.6
33         EXF-CTRL  ...        8.8
34         EXF-CTRL  ...        4.4
35         EXF-CTRL  ...        2.2
36         EXF-CTRL  ...        4.4
37         EXF-CTRL  ...       17.6
38         EXF-CTRL  ...        4.4
```

the "..." part is hiding part. how can I display the whole thing?

```
 import pandas as pd
  2 require_cols=[1,3,6,7,8,9]
  3 df=pd.read_excel('NGXP_6_2_2_dimensions.xlsx',sheet_name='3.1.1 AT&T NBE',usecols=require_cols,skiprows=63,skipfooter=94)
  4 df.dropna(inplace=True)
  5 #df=df.query("Type=='EXF-CTRL'")
  6 #df1=df.head(-96)
  7 print(df)
```

but the out appears with some of the portions hidden:

```
   Application Helm  ... Unnamed: 9
0           Type     ...      RAM L
2          EXF-CTRL  ...        4.4
6          EXF-CTRL  ...        0.6
8          EXF-CTRL  ...        2.2
10         EXF-CTRL  ...        0.4
11         EXF-CTRL  ...        8.8
12         EXF-CTRL  ...        2.2
13         EXF-CTRL  ...        4.4
14         EXF-CTRL  ...        4.4
15         EXF-CTRL  ...        8.8
16         EXF-CTRL  ...        1.1
17         EXF-CTRL  ...        8.8
20         EXF-CTRL  ...        0.1
24         EXF-CTRL  ...        2.2
26         EXF-CTRL  ...        2.2
27         EXF-CTRL  ...        8.8
28         EXF-CTRL  ...        2.2
29         EXF-CTRL  ...        4.4
30         EXF-CTRL  ...        4.4
31         EXF-CTRL  ...        2.2
32         EXF-CTRL  ...        0.6
33         EXF-CTRL  ...        8.8
34         EXF-CTRL  ...        4.4
35         EXF-CTRL  ...        2.2
36         EXF-CTRL  ...        4.4
37         EXF-CTRL  ...       17.6
38         EXF-CTRL  ...        4.4
```

the "..." part is hiding part. how can I display the whole thing?

Comment: Is there a difference between the two script and result blocks? Please [edit] your question and clarify this or remove the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have a lot of columns or their names are too long, so some of them are hidden. You can print the names of all columns with print`(df.columns)`
To show all rows and columns [use](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html):

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)  # print everything rows
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)  # print everything columns
```

Or select not all columns, for example like this:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'a555': [1, 2, 3], 'b555': [1, 2, 3], 'c555': [1, 2, 3], 'd555': [1, 2, 3],
                   'e555': [1, 2, 3], 'f555': [1, 2, 3], 'g555': [1, 2, 3], 'h555': [1, 2, 3],
                   'i555': [1, 2, 3], 'j555': [1, 2, 3], 'k555': [1, 2, 3], 'l555': [1, 2, 3],
                   'm555': [1, 2, 3], 'n555': [1, 2, 3]})

print(df[['a555', 'g555', 'n555']])
```